# How can I alter livejs to run on PHP pages?

Tags: javascript, content-type

Trying to alter the [livejs](http://livejs.com/) script to work with PHP files / files with .php extensions.

I have messed with the parts with the case statements and also the Content-Type but no luck.

Has anyone ever worked with livejs making it work with other file extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try livejs bookmarklet and it works with .php almost without modification. I had to only add `html` in bookmarklet so now I have `http://livejs.com/live.js#html,css,notify` inside bookmarklet. Script doesn't care of file extension.

Even author says:

> Live.js is **independent** of the development framework or language you
>   use, whether it be Ruby, Handcraft, Python, Django, NET, Java, Php,
>   Drupal, Joomla or what-have-you.

**edit:**

`livejs` use `ETag` and `Last-Modified` header to check if file was modified but some servers could don't add `ETag` and `Last-Modified` to PHP files.

You can always add to PHP file (in first line):

```
<?php    
    $file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // your file name 
    $last_modified_time = filemtime($file); 
    $etag = md5_file($file); 

    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified_time)." GMT"); 
    header("Etag: $etag"); 
?>
```

Comment: Adding the ETag worked, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this! Bookmarklet was for some reason not working for me. So I added the php code to my files and it worked.

I have to save the file twice to reflect the changes though. If I figure out why that is, I will update the findings here.

Comment: @AkshayGaur this question is 5 years old. They could change code in livejs many times.

Comment: in addition to the code shown above, you will need to call `opcache_reset();` on most modern php installations, or else you'll end up having to save the file twice (as @AkshayGaur noticed) in order to see the reload.